# Consume touch event inside viewpager with scrollview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, touch-event

I have a `viewpager`, and each page has a `scrollview`. I want to be able to do scroll vertically and also change page horizontally without raising the finger. The problem is that if I start moving the finger vertically, the `scrollview` gets the touch events, but if I start moving the finger horizontally, the event is still consumed by `scrollview`. So I have to raise the finger, and start a new gesture horizontally.

I would like to change this behaviour creating a custom `scrollview`. If I override `onTouchEvent()`, I can detect the direction of the event. So I have made something like:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(){
   if(isVertical()){
        return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

My problem is that when I return false, the `scrollview` stops scrolling, but the touch events are not passed to the `viewpager`, so I can't swipe to next or previous page.

Comment: It might help if you change the current focus to viewpager by calling `pager.requestFocus()` when returning false.

Comment: It doesn't work adding the requestFocus :(